# how do I use regex in awk to filter on a particular column

Tags: awk

how do I use regex in awk to filter on a particular column?

basically I want to be able to find columns that start with c or C e.g. "*^c*" "^C*"or end in 1 or 2 e.g. "*1$" "*2$"

my below attept does not seem to work.

```
> cat file.csv
col1,col2,col3,col4
col1,col2,col3
col1,col2
col1
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
> awk -F, '{print $1}' file.csv
col1
col1
col1
col1
col1
> awk -F, '$1=="col1" {print $1}' file.csv
col1
col1
col1
col1
col1
> awk -F, '$1=="c*" {print $1}' file.csv
>
>
>
> awk -F, '$1~"c*" {print $1}' file.csv
col1
col1
col1
col1
col1
> awk -F, '$1~"*1" {print $1}' file.csv
>
```

### EDIT1

this is a better file to work with

```
> cat file2.csv
col1,col2,col3,col4
dol1,col2,col3
dol1,col2
eol1
fol1,col2,col3,col4,col5
>
> awk -F, '$1~"*1" {print $1}' file2.csv
> awk -F, '{print $1}' file2.csv
col1
dol1
dol1
eol1
fol1
> awk -F, '$1=="col1" {print $1}' file2.csv ## this is the out put I want 
col1
> awk -F, '$1=="c*" {print $1}' file2.csv ## but I want to be able to do it using regex, this attempt failed 
> awk -F, '$1~"^c*" {print $1}' file2.csv ## another failed attempt, just want col1 to be displayed here. 
col1
dol1
dol1
eol1
fol1
>
```

Comment: What's the intended output here? As I understand it, it should match every line in the example, right?

Comment: @NickODell see my edit 1 above

Comment: Can include the intended output as well?

Comment: `awk -F, '$1~/^[Cc]/ || $1~/[12]$/' file` will do for the first column starting in `'C'` or `'c'` OR ending in `'1'` or `'2'`.

Answer (score 2):

The comparison in `awk` for comparing to a regular expression is `str ~ /regex/`. In your case to pick the first field when it begins with `'C'` or `'c'` OR ends with `'1'` or `'2'`, you can do:

```bash
awk -F, '$1~/^[Cc]/ || $1~/[12]$/' file
```

(**note:** the default `print` operation is called when there is no rule `{ ... }`)

**Example Use/Output**

Looking at the first field in the following example does what you specify:

```
$ awk -F, '$1~/^[Cc]/ || $1~/[12]$/' << eof
> a3
> b1
> C3
> c2
> C1
> d3
> e1
> f2
> alligators
> eof
b1
C3
c2
C1
e1
f2
```

`a3` and `d3` are excluded.

Note: to compare every field, you loop over the field numbers within a rule, e.g.

```bash
awk -F, '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i~/^[Cc]/ || $i~/[12]$/) print $i }' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With multi-column input, e.g.

```
$ cat  Cc12multi.txt
a3,z2
b1,z3
C8,H1
c2,d2
C1,d4
d3,d2
e1,e3
f2,c7
```

You would get:

```
$ awk -F, '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i~/^[Cc]/ || $i~/[12]$/) print $i }' Cc12multi.txt
z2
b1
C8
H1
c2
d2
C1
d2
e1
f2
c7
```

Or, to preserve the field locations, you could do, e.g.

```bash
awk -F, '{
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
    if ($i~/^[Cc]/ || $i~/[12]$/) 
      printf (i>1)?",%s":"%s", $i
    else 
      printf (i>1)?",":"  "
  print "" 
}' file
```

(you would need to adjust the output format as desired)

Output with `Cc12multi.txt` as `file`:

```
  ,z2
b1,
C8,H1
c2,d2
C1,
  ,d2
e1,
f2,c7
```

Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 2):

I want firstly to explain why your attempts failed

```
awk -F, '$1~"c*" {print $1}' file.csv
awk -F, '$1~"*1" {print $1}' file.csv
```

do regular expression checks, but not what you think. `c*` means `c` character repeated zero-or-more times, observe that empty string does match that (empty string is c repeated zero times) thus this condition always holds. `*1` means literal ASTERISK (`*`) followed by DIGIT ONE (`1`), as `*` is first character and thus does not have anything to repeat.

In order to express *does start with c character* you might use `/^c/` and to express *does ends with 1 or 2* you might use `/[12]$/`, these two might be welded together using `|` to denote alternative (`OR`) thus becoming `/^c|[12]$/`. Finally we have to accept both lowercase and uppercase c letter, this can be done easily using [`IGNORECASE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Case_002dsensitivity.html) thus code becomes

```
awk -F, -v IGNORECASE=1 '$1~/^c|[12]$/' file.csv
```

which might be also written as

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";IGNORECASE=1}$1~/^c|[12]$/' file.csv
```